# Tableview is interfering with button on a view played over it

Tags: ios, swift, interface-builder

I have a tableView on my view, when the user taps on a certain cell I am showing a view that has a date picker on it, it partially covers the tableView.

The issue that i'm having is that the tableView is hijacking the touch for the button that closes the view containing the date picker. I have tried resizing the tableView to test this theory, it works perfectly then the tableView isn't underneath the button.

Does anyone know how I can prioritise the touches on the button over the tableView?

I have tried bringing the view to the front: `self.view.bringSubviewToFront(self.datePickerView)`

And the views are in the correct order in the storyboard:

[image]

Comment: Would you like share your code?

Comment: It's a confidential project for a client so I can't share screenshots or anything. But it's literally just a storyboard. I have a UIView that is animated in using 'UIView.animateWithDuration' onto the bottom of the view. The part of the view that overlaps the tableView cannot receive touch.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution might be to disable userInteractionEnabled for your table when opening that view. When view is going to be closed, you can anable it again. This will also help avoiding other possible problems (i.e. scrolling table while showing that view).

Comment: Just to be sure - that view cannot be subview of table

Comment: Nope, standard UIView.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `UIView` and `UITableView` is this order in storyboard.
[image]

If not work try to use:

```
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(pickerParentView)
```

Comment: I have already tried both of those. I will update my question to reflect that

Comment: Just create a new project to make this situation happen.